# Meaning of “carve-out”

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

In [this video](https://youtu.be/Psw2UwOEDZI&t=5m6s), starting from 5 mins 6 seconds, Cuomo said:

> But the bill did have that **carve-out** and you said you’ve never been near it.

What does *carve-out* mean here?

I look up the dictionary and find it hard to understand which meanings are relevant.

> *General*: Exception to a rule, severance from a unit, or a parallel or secondary agreement based on a primary agreement.
>
> *Collective bargaining*: Attempt by a subgroup of workers (already represented by one union) to establish a distinct identity as a separate group and be represented by another union.
>
> *Finance*:
>     1. Partial spinoff effected by a parent firm by selling 20 percent or less of its shareholding. This sale provides new capital (and new shareholders) to the parent which may sell off the remaining shares (called stub) at a value inflated by the carveout.
>     2. Creation of a new subsidiary that operates in a new market (such as online sales on the Internet) by leveraging the parent firm's core strengths such as brand recognition and distribution system.
>
> *Insurance*: Service not covered under a main policy but bought separately to supplement the standard policy.

Comment: Did you look up *carve out* in a dictionary? Or google it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I still can't understand it

Comment: Which meaning is applicable depends on the broader context, which we can't answer from the body of your question. Questions have to be self-contained. Can you edit in the longer passage which precedes Cuomo's statement? Maybe you can find a transcript online to make the job easier. Also it'll help you get better answers if you tell us which of your quoted definitions you believe is the best match for the context, and why.

Comment: I see. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you found in the dictionary is completely unrelated to what it means here (I'm surprised that these are given while the more common meaning isn't).

As a verb, to '*carve (out)*' means to engrave, to 'cut something out' (generally in a hard material)

Merriam-Webster defines it as:

> Definition of **carving**
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> 1 :  to cut with
> care or precision carved fretwork
>
> 2 :  to make or get by or as if by
> cutting —often used with out carve out a career
>
> 3 :  to cut into
> pieces or slices carved the turkey
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> 1 :  to cut up
> and serve meat
>
> 2 :  to work as a sculptor or engraver

In your example, it's used as a noun, simply meaning 'something that has been carved out'.

That said, I feel this question would be in a better place on ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: All the dictionary glosses quoted by OP are nouns and they all metaphorically arise from your literal, physical definition of "something carved out". But the context in OP's quote does not support your literal interpretation. Cuomo is the governor of NY state and he's not talking about marble, he's talking about legislation. It is more than likely that one of the glosses OP quotes is the correct one, be we can't know which without further context, which OP has committed to supplying. In any case, this answer is incorrect. I agree the Q would have been better asked on ELL, as OP is an ELL.

Comment: This answer is pointing in the right direction.  "Carve-out" as a noun is a back-formation from the verb phrase.